# Как добавить аапись в Бд через форму html

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/player.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="author"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить в БД">
    </form>


<?php 

    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $nameMusik = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['author'])) {
        $author = htmlspecialchars($_GET['author'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','kinomonster');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    $query = "INSERT INTO musik VALUES($nameMusik, $author";
    $mysqli->query($query);



 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Я сам придумал этот метод, но он не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере, Вы не указываете переменные внутри запросы. Они идут строкой, как есть.

На PHP давно не писал, отвечаю с планшета. Не тестил. 
Должно быть как-то так:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO musik VALUES ("'.$nameMusik.'", "'.$author.'")';
```

Также, советую смотреть в сторону PDO, чтобы не было проблем с безопасностью.

Comment: Все получилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

а во что ему инзертить? ниодного поля в запросе нету

`$query = "INSERT INTO musik (nameMusik_field,author_field) VALUES($nameMusik, $author)";`

подробности http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/INSERT.html

+++

еще после `$mysqli->query()` можно сделать `var_dump($mysqli->error_list)` чтоб посмотреть подробности, почему **метод, но он не работает**

Answer (score 0):

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO musik VALUES($nameMusik, $author)";
```

Comment: Происходит то же самое

Comment: У вас передаются не переменные, а обычная строка.поэтому и не работает