# авторизация на сайте на php

Tags: php

Разбираюсь с авторизацией. В инете мнго скриптов, но у меня они не работают. Почему ? Вот такой например. В видео видно, что он срабатывает.

```html
<?php
$db = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'car.local') or die('ошибка соединения');

mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8") or die('Не установлена кодировка');
 if (!empty($_POST["button_auth"])) {
 
 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
 }
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 if($email == $myrow['email']){
  if($password == $myrow['password']){
   echo "Привет!";
  }
  else{
   echo"пароль введён неверно";
  }
 }
 else{
  echo"Логин введён неверно";
 }
 
 
 
?>
  <form name="auth" action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Пароль</td>
        <td>
          <input type="Password" name="passwod">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <input type="submit" name="button_auth" value="Войти">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Так, а что именно не работает?

Comment: Вы бы хоть мануал потрудились открыть и увидеть что там в `mysqli_query` передавать надо.

Comment: Опоздал, но..
Изменить как минимум
`$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");`
на
`$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");`
или
`$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'")`

Comment: Исправил. Всё равно один ответ-пароль введён неверно.

Answer (score -1):

Плохо смотрите видео, значит. у Вас передаётся переменная `$email` как слово в строке. её надо огородить точками

[Похожая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032767/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-html/1033043#1033043)

Comment: Вы бы хоть код какой написать соизволили.

Comment: А какой ещё код? Регистрация работает, база заполняется. А вызвать данные из базы и сравнить не получается.